# Trying to sort date and time with seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to sort the time with seconds. I am able to sort the minute but not the seconds. I tried few things. I have dynamic data which needs to be sorted in latest order. It works with hours , minutes and AM | PM but not for seconds. I am using moments js.

```
function sortAscending(a, b) {
        const dateA = moment($(a).find('time').text(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a');
        const dateB = moment($(b).find('time').text(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a');

        return dateA.isBefore(dateB) ? 1 : dateA.isAfter(dateB) ? -1 : 0;
    };
```

Do we have any other method to sort the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet is horribly inefficient. I assume you have a list of elements with dates in them. What you can do is iterate through the list once and parse all the dates into timestamps (numbers), then simply sort the list base on that:

```js
let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#container > span"));
let parsedDates = new Map(
    elements.map(e => [e, moment(e.textContent, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a')])
);

// before sorting
console.log(elements.map(e => e.textContent));

elements.sort((a, b) => parsedDates.get(a) - parsedDates.get(b));

// after sorting
console.log(elements.map(e => e.textContent));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <span><time>01/01/2001 01:01:02 AM</time></span>
  <span><time>01/01/2001 01:01:01 AM</time></span>
  <span><time>01/01/2001 01:01:03 AM</time></span>
</div>
```

If you don't want a sorted list of elements and instead you want a sorted list of dates, simply sort the parsedDates list instead:

```js
let elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#container > span"));
let parsedDates = elements.map(e => moment(e.textContent, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a'));

// before sorting
console.log(parsedDates);

parsedDates.sort((a, b) => a - b);

// after sorting
console.log(parsedDates);

// you can even format them
console.log(parsedDates.map(t => t.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <span><time>01/01/2001 01:01:02 AM</time></span>
  <span><time>01/01/2001 01:01:01 AM</time></span>
  <span><time>01/01/2001 01:01:03 AM</time></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second parameter of the method that determines the precision, and not just a single value to check, using day will check for year, month and day.

```
let x = moment();
let y = monent();

x.isBefore(x, 'second'); // true
```